# How to get a field value in mongodb in java for number of records in java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to get a MongoDB field value based on key from the number of documents by using below syntax but not able to get the value. Tried multiple syntax but not able to get the value. Can anyone assist on the issue how to retrieve a MongoDB field value from number of documents.

I am able to connect to MongoDB database and able to get the results based on below query. And the amount object is having the number of documents. From that I need to get a key value from the MongoDB field (Sample.Value). Below is my JSON.

```
How can I get the the Sample.value :123 

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abcdefg"),
    
   
    "Sample" : {
        "value" : "123",
        "color" : "red",
        
    },
    
}

    Query searchQuery = new Query();
       if (value != null && !value.isEmpty())
                searchQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("System.Value").is(value));
            List<Amount> amount = new ArrayList<>();
             amountdetails = mongoOpsTS.find(searchQuery, Amount.class);
            Amount.addAll(amountdetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you used spring-boot? If yes this dependency & mongoTemplate are ready for you to interact with mongoDb.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Example for count the record documents:

```
long amount = mongoTemplate.count(Query.query(where("System.Value").is(value)), EntityClass.class);
```

If you need further example pls refer to this [example](https://github.com/phuongnq1995/spring-boot-mongodb/blob/main/src/main/java/com/phuongnq/mongodb/service/impl/MongoServiceImpl.java)

UPDATED:

If I understand correctly, after having `List<Amount> amount`, you want to get all `System.Value` inside the `Amount` class. Basically, just need to loop through them

```
for (Amount element : amount) {
   String sampleValue = element.getSample().getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @phuongnq1995 for quick response .I am able to connect to mongodb and getting the results . From the results ,need to fetch a mongoDB field value based on key . I am facing an issue while fetching  the value from the mongodb field value  .Can you please help me to get the value from number of documents.

Comment: @Rose See my edited answer, btw you should create a new question instead of updating it.